# Matching parentheses over multiple lines (with awk?)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, latex

I want to filter out footnotes from a LaTeX document using a bash script. It may look like either of these examples:

```tex
Some text with a short footnote.\footnote{Some \textbf{explanation}.}

Some text with a longer footnote.%
  \footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor
     sit amet, etc. etc. etc. \emph{along \emph{multiple} lines}
     but all lines increased indent from the start.}
```

The remains should be:

```tex
Some text with a short footnote.

Some text with a longer footnote.%
```

I don't care about extra whitespace.

Since matching parentheses cannot be done with regular expressions, I presume I cannot use `sed` for this. Is it possible with `awk` or some other tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and null FS splitting the record into chars:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="[\\\\]footnote"; ORS=""; FS="" }
NR>1 {
    braceCnt=0
    for (charPos=1; charPos<=NF; charPos++) {
        if ($charPos == "{") { ++braceCnt }
        if ($charPos == "}") { --braceCnt }
        if (braceCnt == 0)   { break }
    }
    $0 = substr($0,charPos+1)
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk  file
Some text with a short footnote.

Some text with a longer footnote.%
```

Answer (score 2):

Using recursive regex in command line `perl`, you can match matching parentheses as this:

```
perl -00pe 's/%?\s*\\footnote({(?:[^{}]*|(?-1))*})//g' file

Some text with a short footnote.

Some text with a longer footnote.
```

For regex details [here is regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VjcmfO/1)